# ReferenceError: change is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function for an edit process. When the user edits the value and clicks the button then it will save to the database. But currently, when I click the button, I get the error

> ReferenceError: change is not defined

Below is my code. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong and help me to fix it?

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.edit').click(function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.is('#editbox')) {
            return;
        }
        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        $(this).addClass('ajax');
        $(this).html('<input id="editbox"  size="5" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        $('#editbox').select();
    });

    $('td.edit').ready(function () {
        function change() {
            arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
            if (event.which == 13) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "clientnetworkpricelist/update.php",
                    data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1],
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                    }
                });
            }

        }

    });
    $('#editbox').live('blur', function () {

        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<td><img onclick="change()"  src="/image/Picture1.png" style="margin:0 0 0 6px;;cursor:pointer" ></td>
```

Comment: The `change` function is not defined in global scope, hence it cannot be called from an inline event handler. Just use jQuery to bind the handler, the same way you bind the handler to `$('td.edit')`. Also, FYI, `$('td.edit').ready` is unnecessary, since the this statement is already inside a `ready` handler. See the documentation for ready: http://api.jquery.com/ready/.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have: `$('td.edit').ready(function ()` where your html is `<td><img...`. No `edit` class. Second, maybe you should try this:

HTML:

```
<td class="edit"><img src="/image/Picture1.png" style="margin:0 0 0 6px;;cursor:pointer"></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td.edit').on('click', function() {
        //your magic from change() function
    });
});
```

Also [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function is deprecated from jQuery 1.7. You should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

---

EDIT:

If you want to call action just `onClick` so why you trying to catch `enter` press? Remember to add to your `<td>` where button is a `edit` class.

Change this:

```
$('td.edit').ready(function () {
    function change() {
        arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
        if (event.which == 13) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "clientnetworkpricelist/update.php",
                data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1],
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                }
            });
        }

    }

});
```

To this:

```
$('td.edit img').on('click', function() {
    arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" "); //it will be clicked <img>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "clientnetworkpricelist/update.php",
        data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1],
        success: function (data) {
            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        }
    });
});
```

---

EDIT:

Personally I'll do something like this:

HTML:

```
<td class="edit"><a href="#" data-id="1" data-field="somefield"><img src="exp.jpg" /></a></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('td.edit a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "clientnetworkpricelist/update.php",
        data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + $(this).attr('data-id') + "&field=" + $(this).attr('data-field'),
        success: function (data) {
            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks buti tried what you said it shows an error"
TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined
 

arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" "); //it will be clicked <img>" if i click the image it opening the edit box in the same because of class="edit"

Comment: I'm guessing that `td.edit` is a parent of `img`? Checkout `parent()` function. Ex. `arr = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ');`. I don't know how far desired `td` is.

Comment: thanks now it little good but now it not taking the edited value it shows "field undefined
rowid undefined
value undefined

value=undefined&rowid=undefined&field=undefined"

Comment: Read it carefully. Check my last suggestion. I guess that's it. You should solve it from here.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing

```
$('td.edit').ready(function () {

     //change function definition

});
```

You can bind the function to its click event there it self

```
$('td.edit').click(function () {
        arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
        if (event.which == 13) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "clientnetworkpricelist/update.php",
                data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1],
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                }
            });
        }

});
```

and remove `onclick="change()"` code from html

Comment: thanks for reply i want to perform function when button is clicked